# What should be the output of this Javascript program having asynchronous operations?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, asynccallback

I'm expecting this code to run, then after 2 seconds, the execution stack will become empty and there is one callback of `setTimeout`. I'm expecting this as I would expect the message queue and the job queue to be empty(as the promise is not resolved yet).

So, the `Callback` is printed first, then after 3 seconds, the promise is resolved and its callback is placed in the job queue and the message `Promise is resolved` should be printed. But that is not what is happening. So what I am missing here?

The code is:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("Callbcack");
}, 0);
 
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("Inside promise");
    let ms = 5000 + new Date().getTime();
    while (new Date() < ms) {}
 
    resolve("Promise is resolved");
 
}).then((data) => {console.log(data)})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
})
 
var ms = 2000 + new Date().getTime();
while (new Date() < ms) {}
```

Comment: you have a blocking loop inside your Promise's callback and another in the outer scope.   These prevent the message queue from being processed.

Comment: while loops are not asynchronous, even if you put them into a promise.

Comment: Had there been some asynchronous operation(like getting data from DB) in place of the for loop in Promise which takes some time to process(let's say 10 sec). Would it make any difference in the output?

Answer (score 0):

You have just discovered JavaScript's [microtasks](https://javascript.info/microtask-queue). In short, there is actually two different callback queues. One for the microtasks and one for the macrotasks. In your case, the callback of your `Promise` is a microtask, while the `setTimeout` callback is a macrotask. The microtasks queue is always handled before the macrotasks queue.

So, even if you queued `function() { console.log("Callbcack"); }` before `(data) => { console.log(data) }`, the second one will always execute first, no matter how long you block the thread before resolving the `Promise`, because both queues will be handled when the top-level code has finished executing.

Comment: and neither will be processed if you're in the middle of a timed `while` loop...

Comment: Yes, that just explains why the `setTimeout` callback is guaranteed to execute after the `Promise` callback, in contrary to what OP expected

Comment: These asynchronous operations(setTimeout and promise execution) are handled by Web APIs or C/C++ APIs(if the environment is Nodejs). So, am I right in saying that after 2 seconds, global execution context(top level) has been popped-off from the call stack? If that is the case, then after 2 seconds the global context has been popped-off from the call stack and now the event loop looks up in the message queue and micro-task queue, at this moment the microtask queue is empty but there is one callback(of setTimeout) in the message, so the event loop will place it on the call stack and execute it.

Comment: Not exactly, because you also have a top-level `Promise`. The `(resolve, reject) => {` function passed in the `Promise` constructor is being executed synchronously (only `.then((data) => {console.log(data)})` is asynchronous) so in your example the execution stack is empty after 7s. At this moment, one microtask and one macrotask have been queued, so they execute in the right priority order

Answer (score 0):

Promise executor function is run synchronously (precisely at the time you call `new Promise(executor)`) so promise is resolved within running the top level code (at the initial stack) after 5000 ms.

Then, microtask queue is executed, so you see result of `console.log(data)`.

Then, js (event loop) is free to run the next asynchronous piece which happen to be the timer handler.

Comment: Had there been some asynchronous operation(like getting data from DB) in place of the for loop in Promise which takes some time to process(let's say 10 sec). Would it make any difference in the output?

Comment: @sv2311 if `resolve` wasn't called on the initial stack but asynchronously 10s later, `console.log(data)` would be fired last. You can check this by faking db call with `setTimeout`.